# Abide Password Validation

Tags: zurb-foundation, abide

I have a password field and I was under the impression that these automatically validate with abide?

I'm using Foundation 5.

Currently I can input anything I like and it will pass validation.

I know abide is working correctly as other fields fail.

Do I need to type in a pattern for it to work? Is there a specific one for passwords?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you need to type in a pattern, if you only set the *required* flag, no matter if you set a single character, it will pass. You need to add something

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="txt_password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required pattern="alpha_numeric">
```

It will restrict to alpha-numeric passwords.

You can use the [predefined patterns](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html#predefined-patterns) or create your [custom patterns](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html#custom-named-patterns) at will.